# infinite scroll loading dom elements, then applying jquery to the elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a script called showContents.js with the following.

```
jQuery(function() {
  //hide element 
  jQuery(".targetDiv").css("display", "none");
  // Hook the button click
    
  jQuery(".showEpisodes").click(function(e) {
  // To prevent reloading of page
  e.preventDefault(); 

  //toggle and hide all other div tags
  jQuery('#'+$(this).attr('target')).slideToggle('fast', function(){
    jQuery('.targetDiv').not($(this)).slideUp();

    });
  });
});
```

This will on element click with the class of 'showEpisodes' show the corresponding div and hide all others.

I have a JavaScript file that generates articles with info from a JSON file and expands a div if clicked on.

This works fine, but scaling this process takes a while to load all elements immediately. So I wanted to load rows of articles on scroll.

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        i += 3;
       parseMovieRow(Json, i);
    }
};
```

They come in rows of 3. As soon as I do this, the script showContents.js is not applied to the generated articles.

How do I dynamically apply jQuery functions to items generated in JavaScript?

Comment: Instead of `.click()` use [on.("click", function(){...})](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, i think it's because the movie row isn't in the dom, the jquery is applied, then movie rows are added but the jquery isnt applied?

Comment: As @Gerard suggested try using `jQuery("body").on('click','.showEpisodes',function(e) {` instead of `jQuery(".showEpisodes").click(function(e) {`

Comment: Oh...awesome... I was wrong. Thanks, for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the click event to nearest static ancestor. `document` will work in this case, albeit it will not be very efficient.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", ".showEpisodes", function(e){
   //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before appending the elements to the document. You should make them into jQuery objects and then bind your events to them.

```
var myHtml = "<div>foo</div>";

var el = $(myHtml);

el.on("click", your_callback);

$("#my_container").append(el);
```

Edit: the accepted answer will scan all the elements (that are in the click event) and their parents every time there is a click on the page in order to see if it matches your .showEpisodes which is slow and as he mentioned inefficient. It works, but you should not use it when possible.